# Connect to a live database with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I've a question to the mySQL Workbench.

I want to connect to the mysql DB at the domain aaa.com. I write at the connection options these dates:

```
Hostname: www.aaa.com
Port: Which port do i have to write in?
Username: Username of the DB (which is 100% correct)
Password: Password of the DB (which is 100% correct)
Default Schema: Name of the DB (which is 100% correct)
```

If I click connect there is following error:

> "Access denied"

Comment: Generally the port would be `3306`.

Comment: Port :3306 I suspect  it should be the remote db server , please dig out how to access the remote db server ...there should some configuration on server side also please verify it :) @Raffinatore

Comment: [Refer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html) here to see your grant permission

Answer (score 4):

Also you can ssh tunnel:

Create a new connection, select Standard TCP/IP over SSH.

For SSH host name enter your domain aaa.com (the domain you would SSH to).

For SSH username enter your SSH username, so if if you ssh test_user@aaa.com your user is test_user.

Store your SSH password or key files, which ever you use.

The Mysql hostname should be 127.0.0.1 if the mysql server is on the server you are SSH'ing to, else the IP or host name of you Mysql server.

Mysql server user - your mysqsl user.

And your Mysql server password.

This way your database isn't externally acceptable, meaning no one can trying to access it from outside your server on port 3306, but you still have access it through Workbench

Comment: I strongly recommend using an SSH connection instead opening the MySQL port on the server. It's too easy to attack the server that way. You need an SSH server on the target machine, however, which is not the case for Windows boxes. Use 3rd party SSH servers there. Also: to increase security don't use the default SSH port but chose an arbitrary one in the higher area (like 44455) to make it harder for port scanners.

Answer (score 0):

Contact your web hosting company to make sure they allow remote connections first. It's disabled by some hosts. Default port will be 3306.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for security reasons, the incoming connections from external domains will be disabled. Contact your host if that is allowed.

By the way, the **default port of MySQL** is `3306`.

---

If you have `root` access to phpMyAdmin, you can see if the port is opened using this tutorial: [Install MySQL and enable remote access](http://blog.vinhkhoa.com/article/Set-up-a-Railo-Apache-MySQL-host-on-Ubuntu-Part-2-install-MySQL-and-enable-remote-access).